# read a text file and search a string in android

Tags: android

I my android application,i would like to read a text file which is placed on the sdcard. Read the file to search for a string: "some string" and would like to get the value for that string.
Is there any way that i can do that in android.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean with value for that string? Do you mean its position in the file or do you want have a key value file?

Comment: Like suppose in my file i have something like Name:Reshmi;
I just want to search name in the file and then get Reshmi from it.

Comment: Like initially how can i search for a string in the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File file = new File(your file);

```
    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                    int len = 0;
                    byte[] data1 = new byte[1024];
            while ( -1 != (len = in.read(data1)) ){

                                 if(new String(data1, 0, len).contains(Your String))
                                     //do something...
                     }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Umesh.Its working fine.Do you have any idea like how i can get the text next to it.

Comment: store the data coming from the web in a string then use indexOf property and find out the index of your string.

startIndex = index_of_your_string + yourString.length(), 
then use substring and retrieve the next string.

Comment: Not granted, Umesh. You are searching for a pattern inside a 1024 bytes buffer. If the wanted word is hacked by buffer, can be never found.

For an easy example, lets reduce the buffer size to 10.

Search the word "pumpkin" on text "i like this tasty pumpkin"

No match on first buffer, no match on second "s tasty pu" and no match on last "mpkin".

Same to bigger buffer sizes.