# How to search for contents of file and read only a part of File

Tags: android

I am using JSON-RPC. When i send request to server i get a response from server which is almost 2MB long. There is no new line character in the data. As we know, it is not possible to store all the 2MB data inside string, i had to write the data to a file.

This is what my file looks like:

> [{"data1":"data1",....},{...},...]

I want to read the data part-by-part, like get the string between "{" and "}", so that i get the exact contents of 1 JSON Object, after which i can parse the data.

I have referred to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3635147/928861), but I won't get the position of "{" and "}" to copy my JSON data.

Is there a way to implement such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use

> [com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.JsonReader](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html)

And compile your object as you get the data from the server. No need for storing to a String or writing and reading from a file

Comment: Can he really do that if he has to download a 2Mb file and turn it into a json object in ram ?

Comment: well he eventually will store it to memory. so i will say yes. If he has to reuse random parts then a caching system maybe be a better option but nothing like that is specified. Also he may store it directly to sqlLite

Comment: I think he outta be better with a caching system. His requirement to get some parts of the json only will be easier to fulfill.

Comment: if he want only a particular segment then he can keep only that one to memory. Anyway @Pallavi many options all correct.Just choose based on what you need

Comment: @Snicolas he doesn't need to convert all 2MB to json. Think of it like SAX but for Json. He can keep only what he needs.

Comment: Ok, I caught it finally. Sorry, long to realize that you used the reader and not a json object directly. Receive my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [regex pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

More or less something like this :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "{(.*?)}" );
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( response );
while( matcher.find() ) {
  String jsonString = "{" + matcher.group( 0 ) +"}" ;
  //parse the json
}
```